# LaTeX3: \dim_eval:n and e-TeX dimension expression

Tags: latex3, dimension-expressions

Why does the following code not yield the expected result `264pt`? Are non-integers not allowed as factors in e-TeX dimension expressions?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_set:Nn\l_dimen_tl{120pt}
\tl_set:Nn\l_mult_tl{2.2}
\tl_set:Nx\l_result_tl{\dim_eval:n{\l_dimen_tl*\l_mult_tl}}

\l_result_tl %gives 240.0pt.2

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

e-TeX dimension expressions need the fractional part as the dimension: you can multiply by integers and integer ratios only. So

```
\tl_set:Nn\l_dimen_tl{120}
\tl_set:Nn\l_mult_tl{2.2pt}
\tl_set:Nx\l_result_tl{\dim_eval:n{\l_mult_tl*\l_dimen_tl}}
```

works fine. (This is of course a general e-TeX restriction, and is not unique to LaTeX3 code.)

Comment: I guess we need to give more detail on 'dimension expressions' in the documentation.

Comment: so e-TeX dimexpr syntax is anything but intuitive and not usable for many, even the simplest purposes. Rational numbers must be hard coded as fractions of integers. As such fractions are impossible to be generated from arbitrary user provided input, I will have to return to `calc` or `l3calc` which provide the `\real{}` command.

Comment: @Alexander: Remember that `\dim_eval:n` is a code function, for setting dimensions which can reasonably be expected to be 'sane'. For user input, it may currently be necessary to do other things, but I'm not clear on the type of input you have. I'd personally do everything using `l3fp` as it looks like you want floating-point operations.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. The rational number given by the user is to finally scale a box whose dimensions (after some other manipulations) are stored in tl variables instead of dim registers (to reduce use of the latters). To get the final values I simply wanted to have them multiplied by the scaling factor within `\dim_eval:n{}` which seems to be impossible after all. Now, as a workaround, I assign the current box dimension values to a temporary dim register and put the scale factor in front of it (in the traditional manner).

Comment: @Alexander: With 32k registers available, I'd encourage you to use `dim` for dimension data and not to worry about 'saving' stuff. Bruno Le Floch is currently working on an expandable `fp` implementation, which should allow arbitrary manipulations within expansion contexts, including `\dim_eval:n`.

Comment: I'm just realizing that I've been working on that FPU for more than 13 months...

Answer (score 5):

The new FPU, which will be available on CTAN around late june 2012, allows for expandable computations.  So to take your example (using a proper dimension register rather than a token list),

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim { 120pt }
\tl_set:Nn \l_mult_tl { 2.2 }
\tl_set:Nx \l_result_tl
  { \fp_to_dim:n { \l_tmpa_dim * \l_mult_tl } }

\l_result_tl % gives 264pt

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Although Alexander mentioned his work-around in a separate comment, I just wanted to mention for completeness the ‘simple’ solution here: `\dim_eval:n` can only do calculations with actual TeX dimension registers, so replacing the token list variable to hold the dimension by a real `dim` fixes the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim {120pt}
\tl_set:Nn \l_mult_tl {2.2}
\tl_set:Nx \l_result_tl { \dim_eval:n { \l_mult_tl \l_tmpa_dim } }

\l_result_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oops, so what I give above is a huge overkill :).

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch — Depending on the type of input data he's working with, though, your solution is still better because it'll work in all circumstances!