# Why do I need \fp_to_dim:n in my dimension expression?

Tags: expl3, dimensions, dimension-expressions

I’m trying to use an `expel` floating point variable (`\l_@@_last_machine_row_x_fp`) inside a calculation of a dimension (`\l_@@_bar_width_dim`).
In the following code `\BarA` works (with a solution from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61141/4918)), while `\BarB` doesn’t work.

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn\makeatletter

% @@ = mymodule

\dim_new:N \l_@@_bar_width_dim

\dim_new:N \l_@@_x_dim
\dim_set:Nn \l_@@_x_dim { 8mm }

\fp_new:N \l_@@_last_machine_row_x_fp

\NewDocumentCommand { \BarA } { m } {
   \fp_add:Nn \l_@@_last_machine_row_x_fp { 1.5 }% arbitrary value
   \dim_set:Nn \l_@@_bar_width_dim {
      \fp_to_dim:n {
         (#1 - \l_@@_last_machine_row_x_fp)
         *
         \l_@@_x_dim
      }
   }
   \rule { \l_@@_bar_width_dim } { 1ex }
}
\NewDocumentCommand { \BarB } { m } {
   \fp_add:Nn \l_@@_last_machine_row_x_fp { 1.5 }% arbitrary value
   \dim_set:Nn \l_@@_bar_width_dim {
      (#1 - \l_@@_last_machine_row_x_fp)
      *
      \l_@@_x_dim
   }
   \rule { \l_@@_bar_width_dim } { 1ex }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff\makeatother

\begin{document}
\BarA{5}% arbitrary value

\BarB{15}% arbitrary value
\end{document}
```

And I wonder why I need `\fp_to_dim:n` in this case, since `\l_@@_x_dim` is already a dimension multiplied by a unit free value `(#1 - \l_@@_last_machine_row_x_fp)`.

<sub>My example code is taken from a package im developing at the moment and obviously does’t make much sense for itself ;-)</sub>

Comment: I think `\dim_set:Nn \l_@@_bar_width_dim { \fp_to_decimal:n { ... } \l_@@_x_dim }` should also work (and would IMHO be a bit clearer). Anyway, you need to convert the fp from its internal representation into something usable in `\dimexpr...\relax` (which in the end is what evaluates the dimension expression)

Comment: @clemens: Thanks. `\fp_to_decimal` is indeed clearer, but then I must omit the `*`. Would you make an answer out of your comment? And you said that the fp has to be converted, then why `(#1 - \fp_use:N \l_@@_last_machine_row_x_fp)` doesn’t work?

Comment: And is there an overview for all the different variable types when is need `\xx_use:N \l_tmpa_xx`  and when a single ` \l_tmpa_xx` is enough?

Comment: @Tobi All of the variable types have accessors: `tl` is an exception in that the accessor is not required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I try

```
\fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp { 3.14 }
\cs_show:N \l_tmpa_fp
```

I get

```
> \l_tmpa_fp=macro:->\s__fp \__fp_chk:w 10{1}{3140}{0000}{0000}{0000};.
```

which shows that `\l_tmpa_fp` is not suitable for being used in the context of a `<dimension expression>`. By the way, the standard meaning of `\s__fp` is `\relax`, which is relevant as far as it shows the reason for errors when you try doing that.

The functions in the `fp` module are made so that expandability is ensured, but with the side effect of not simply storing a number; think to the case of the expression `0.1234e-12` that you can't simply use in the context you want.

On the other hand, `\fp_to_decimal:n` returns a decimal representation of the `<floating point expression>` given as argument, which can be used as a factor in front of a dimension expression.

I'd be wary of using `\l_@@_x_dim` in the context of a floating point expression, even if it produces the same result: they are different animals. There is `\dim_to_fp:n` for conversion.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! Regarding “I'd be wary of using \l_@@_x_dim”: Actually I don't want to. The `\fp_to_dim:n` is only used because to was the first solution I found. Now I use `\fp_to_decimal` as suggested by clemens.